# Locating GPS locations using GeoJSON

Tags: geolocation, gps, gis, geojson

I've got a **GeoJSON** file of administrative borders i.e. **state and county**, and a CSV file with 12,500+ named GPS coordinates located within the geographic area.

My boss wants me to use the GeoJSON identify the county for each GPS location so I ended up with a CSV file (format) like;

```
LOCNAME, LOCLONG, LOCLAT, COUNTY, STATE
```

Is there any tool that can do this?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Questions asking us to find or recommend a tool are off topic. You can, instead, ask a question about the trouble you're having doing this on your own. I recommend reading the pinned articles in the [help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use QGIS to do this. You may import your geojson polygon file and import the csv containing coordinates as a point layer.

Follow the tutorial here: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/points_in_polygon.html

Comment: Thank you very much eNVy. From just looking at QGIS, I think I can get it to work. Was already writing a NodeJS script to do it but I think this will be much less tedious.